# .NET MVC - Custom Edit form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**EDIT v2:**  - SOLVING STEP

Wrote custom ModelBinder and now it works. Additionally I tryed out and noticed, that it would work with the Default ModelBinder if the Boolean value is parsed into the hidden input as string ("boolean.toString()"). 
But with the Deafault ModelBinder I wouldn't have catched this.

---

**EDIT v1:**

I have might have moved on by adding hidden inputs of the remaining fields. Now it appears to not bind the form values with the model properly...

From what I understand the Default Binder, when I've got ALL field names named same as the form input name attributes  (int season ....

I might need to write my own binder, but than that Model elegance, which I so much expect,  goes out of the window.

Still there might be better for me so far unknown solution. Any suggestions and help appreciated.

---

**ORIGINAL:**

Got an issue regarding creation and being able to construct my own edit action in which I will change only few attributes (in this case the season and the episode fields) and I want it to work with the model, not its single fields.

I got this model...

```
public class Entry
{
    public int entryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 99)]
    public int season { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 99)]
    public int episode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Boolean button_dark { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int showID { get; set; }
    public virtual Show show { get; set; }

    public int? pictureID { get; set; }
    public virtual Picture picture { get; set; }

    public Entry () {
        season = 0;
        episode = 0;
    }
}
```

... and I got classic GET and POST actions in the controller...

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        Entry entry = db.Entries.Find(id);
        if (entry == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(entry);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Entry entry)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Home");
        }
        return View(entry);
    }
```

... and in the view I essentialy have.

```
    <form action="/Entry/Index/@Model.entryID" method="post">
         <input type="number" name="season" value="@Model.season" />
         <input type="number" name="episode" value="@Model.episode"/>
         <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

From what I have read about the Model Binder, it shoud chew it just ok. (I hope I did't missinterpreted or missunderstood anything)
When submiting the form i get this exception at the "db.SaveChanges();" statement.

System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

I know what it says, but don't know why. And as a quite newbie in the .NET MVC I don't understand other forum posts to the exception itself.

Does anyone PLEASE know where and what should I do or read to help me with that?

Many thanks.

Comment: How is your context (db) created? Is it a new context for each request, or are you reusing the same context across requests?

Comment: Can you try with modal binding? 
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.season)

Comment: @EricKing as field of the controller "private DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();" with which I work everywhere in the controller.

Comment: @Deepu shouldn't be any different because the important form code is the same, just a few added validation atributes is what i see. Anyway, doesn't work either.

Comment: Check this = http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
http://forums.asp.net/t/1976639.aspx?DbUpdateConcurrencyException
http://www.dotnetbips.com/articles/58216146-d464-42cb-b60d-15215467b107.aspx

Comment: @Deepu yeah, it would probably work as it is a manipulation with the "standalone" attributes. Actualy I applicated that princip in few other apps. But it doesn't solve my problem at the whole-at-once Model level, which I want to learn how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now I will summarize this, for me a little unintuitive,  solution to my problem...

1. You need to have all model fields in the form (even if they were
   hidden)
2. Be sure to insert right data types in the input values,
   otherwise the binder won't bind succesfully data to the model (for
   example: Boolean must go there as String)